# Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

This is my index.html

`<form action="submitForm" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" onclick="" />
    </form>`

This is my web.xml

```
`<servlet>
<servlet-name>submitForm</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>student.StudentSurveyFormSubmit</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>submitForm</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/submitForm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`
```

And my servlet class

`package student;
 @WebServlet("/StudentSurveyFormSubmit")
    public class StudentSurveyFormSubmit extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1>" + "Hi, "+request.getParameter("firstName") +"  I am here" + "</h1>");
    }}`

Whenever I deploy my war file and click sumbot button I get an exception as :

The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class student.StudentSurveyFormSubmit
    org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you have more of that error message? Usually there is another stacktrace labelled "Caused by".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `web.xml` to define servlet then remove `@WebServlet` annotation, as now you have 2 different mappings.